# Show $V=\ker(f(T))\oplus \ker(g(T))$ if $T$ has characteristic polynomial $f(t)g(t)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $T$ is a linear transformation of a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ having characteristic polynomial $f(t)g(t)$ where $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime. Show $V=\ker(f(T))\oplus \ker(g(T))$.

Comment: That's $\oplus$ and not $\otimes.$ Hint: use Bezout and Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: @ julien Yes. You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f,g$ are coprime, $uf+vg=1$ for some $u,v$. Hence if $x\in V$ then $x=u(T)f(T)x+v(T)g(T)x$ and $f(T)x\in {\rm Ker}g(T),g(T)x\in {\rm Ker}f(T) $ etc.